# Wanted to know whether I can start learning Angularjs without knowing advance JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am a beginner in JavaScript. I know the basics though but not an expert in JavaScript. I just wanted to know whether I can start learning Angularjs without knowing advance JavaScript? And what are the best resources where I can start learning advance JavaScript?

Comment: That all depends on your own learning ability, and try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: Let me take an analogy: if you know how to use `C` pointers, you will be better at `Java` or `C#`. Same goes here. You will need some knowledge to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Yes Go ahead! Start from http://www.w3schools.com/angular/

Answer (score 1):

The best course I know for learning Angular JS is [udemy.com/learn-angularjs](https://www.udemy.com/learn-angularjs/). I took the whole 6.5 hours course and I'm utterly satisfied of it. However, after following this course, I was sure of two things : 1. AngularJS is terrific; 2. it's not for JS beginners. You have to understand a lot of things in JS, starting with objects and scope, and have a decent experience with it before diving into Angular. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Everyone got downvoted, everyone gets downvoted all the time without any reason or comments on StackOverflow. Go f**k yourself with that stupid epidemic